# Variable is defined, but never used warning JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a login page in React and am sending the variables and login functions down to other files through `<Component.Provider value={} />` method, but it is not registering that I'm referring to variables above. How do I fix that?

[image]

Note: `state` is minimised, but it should be:

```
var state = {
    token: null,
    userId: null,
};
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
// import {Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import AuthPage from './pages/Auth';
import EventsPage from './pages/Events';
import BookingsPage from './pages/Bookings';
import MainNavigation from './components/Navigation/MainNavigation';
import AuthContext from './context/auth-context';



function App() {
     var state = {
        token: null,
        userId: null,
    };
    function login(token, userId, tokenExpiration) {
        this.setState({token: token, userId: userId});
    };
    function logout() {
        this.setState({token: null, userId: null})
    };
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
     <React.Fragment>
         <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token: this.state.token, userId: this.state.userId, login: this.login, logout: this.logout }}>
      <MainNavigation />
       <main className="main-content">
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/auth" replace={true}/>} />
            <Route path="/auth" element={<AuthPage />} />
            <Route path="/events" element={<EventsPage/>} />
            <Route path="/bookings" element={<BookingsPage/>} />
         </Routes>
       </main>
         </AuthContext.Provider>
     </React.Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Warning:

```
WARNING in src\App.js
  Line 1:17:   'Component' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
  Line 16:10:  'state' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 20:14:  'login' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  Line 23:14:  'logout' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Comment: Did you read the warnings? The first, `Component` is imported but never used so just don't import it. You're also using `var state = ...` but also `this.state.*` which aren't the same thing. You shouldn't be using either, you should be using `useState`.

Comment: I also don't see where you are using any of the referenced things the warnings mention.

Comment: @KevinB `Component` is imported in one of the top lines but never used. `state` is defined with `var` but used as `this.state` which actually doesn't work like that. `login` and `logout` are accessed as `this.login` and `this.logout` but defined with `function` so once again, it doesn't work like that. Seems like OP is trying to get used to functional components as many of these errors seem built upon class component structure.

Comment: when I write state = {} it says state is not defined so that's why I use var state

Comment: in provider value I send the values and methods which I use in another file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Incorrect components usage in React
2. Incorrect usage of Context API

You should use a class component to use its methods, like `this.setState`.

But you use these for functional components:

- *[Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)*
- *[Function and Class Components](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)*
- *[Context.Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)*

P.S.: If you want to transfer data to a child component, where it will be used, use props.